# how to give root permissions to hadoop users in r language

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs

I have been importing hdfs files through `readLines(textConnection(rhread("/hotel_81480.dat",type="text")),n=1)` and saved the 1 line in an array `ajs[]`.The data consisted in array is of type `number.Now` Im using `barplot(ajs[])` command to draw a bar graph.FAcing the error :

```
 Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified

Error in X11(d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize, d$gamma, d$colortype,  : 
  unable to start device X11cairo
In addition: Warning message:
In function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''
```

hope to get any suggestion

Comment: Your title and question body seem unrelated. Your error stems from R to open a graphic window. Maybe use ssh -X?

Comment: ssh -X doesnt work . There may be something more in with this command

Comment: For your next question, please try to be clear in what you need exactly. Your title mentioned something about root, but your question did not. So next time, start your question with something like: `I have the following problem, when I try to create a barplot when logged as root, I get the following error:` and then show your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit cryptic, but from the title and question body combined I deduce you want to start X windows as root. Simply pasting your error into google led me to the following [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/xlib-connection-to-0-0-refused-by-server-331779/). This suggests:

*quote:*
As normal user, you can run:

```
xhost local:root
```

and then root will be able to open X programs. You can edit `/root/.bashrc` and add the following line:

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/name/.Xauthority
```

Where "name" is the user account name that you use. After editing `/root/.basrc`, you won't have to issue the command `xhost local:root` anymore after X starts.